# Understanding @MapsId annotation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

As per [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id), the explanation for `@MapsId` annotation is given as :

> In the embedded id object, the association is represented as the
>   identifier of the associated entity. But you can link its value to a
>   regular association in the entity via the @MapsId annotation. The
>   @MapsId value correspond to the property name of the embedded id
>   object containing the associated entity's identifier. In the database,
>   it means that the Customer.user and the CustomerId.userId properties
>   share the same underlying column (user_fk in this case).

```
@Entity
class Customer {
   @EmbeddedId CustomerId id;
   boolean preferredCustomer;

   @MapsId("userId")
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="userfirstname_fk", referencedColumnName="firstName"),
      @JoinColumn(name="userlastname_fk", referencedColumnName="lastName")
   })
   @OneToOne User user;
}

@Embeddable
class CustomerId implements Serializable {
   UserId userId;
   String customerNumber;

   //implements equals and hashCode
}

@Entity 
class User {
   @EmbeddedId UserId id;
   Integer age;
}

@Embeddable
class UserId implements Serializable {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;

   //implements equals and hashCode
}
```

Also it says:

> While not supported in JPA, Hibernate lets you place your association
>   directly in the embedded id component (instead of having to use the
>   @MapsId annotation).

```
@Entity
class Customer {
   @EmbeddedId CustomerId id;
   boolean preferredCustomer;
}

@Embeddable
class CustomerId implements Serializable {
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="userfirstname_fk", referencedColumnName="firstName"),
      @JoinColumn(name="userlastname_fk", referencedColumnName="lastName")
   }) 
   User user;
   String customerNumber;

   //implements equals and hashCode
}

@Entity 
class User {
   @EmbeddedId UserId id;
   Integer age;
}

@Embeddable
class UserId implements Serializable {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;


   //implements equals and hashCode
}
```

I tried to generate the tables using Hibernate itself (`hbm2ddl.auto=create`) to understand how the `@MapsId` annotation is used. Here are my observations:

If my entity declaration for `Customer` and `User` are like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
   @EmbeddedId CustomerId id;
   boolean preferredCustomer;

   @MapsId("userId")
   @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name="userfirstname_fk", referencedColumnName="firstName"),
      @JoinColumn(name="userlastname_fk", referencedColumnName="lastName")
   })
   @OneToOne User user;
}

@Entity 
@Table(name="TBL_USER")
class User {
   @EmbeddedId UserId id;
   Integer age;
}
```

Then the DDL statements generated by Hibernate says:

```
Hibernate: create table TBL_CUSTOMER (customerNumber varchar2(255 char) not null, preferredCustomer number(1,0) not null, userfirstname_fk varchar2(255 char) not null, userlastname_fk varchar2(255 char) not null, primary key (customerNumber, userfirstname_fk, userlastname_fk))
Hibernate: create table TBL_USER (firstName varchar2(255 char) not null, lastName varchar2(255 char) not null, age number(10,0), primary key (firstName, lastName))
Hibernate: alter table TBL_CUSTOMER add constraint UK_chvh5mukc81xk9t6fis3skab  unique (userfirstname_fk, userlastname_fk)
Hibernate: alter table TBL_CUSTOMER add constraint FK_chvh5mukc81xk9t6fis3skab foreign key (userfirstname_fk, userlastname_fk) references TBL_USER
```

Now if I change my `Customer` entity to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
   @EmbeddedId CustomerId id;
   boolean preferredCustomer;

   @OneToOne User user;
}
```

Then the DDL statements are:

```
Hibernate: create table TBL_CUSTOMER (customerNumber varchar2(255 char) not null, firstName varchar2(255 char), lastName varchar2(255 char), preferredCustomer number(1,0) not null, user_firstName varchar2(255 char), user_lastName varchar2(255 char), primary key (customerNumber, firstName, lastName))
Hibernate: create table TBL_USER (firstName varchar2(255 char) not null, lastName varchar2(255 char) not null, age number(10,0), primary key (firstName, lastName))
Hibernate: alter table TBL_CUSTOMER add constraint FK_et3bgekef237d4kov7b9oqt85 foreign key (user_firstName, user_lastName) references TBL_USER
```

In this case, I see 2 extra columns (firstname & lastname) for `TBL_CUSTOMER` if I remove `@MapsId` and `@JoinColumn` annotations. Also an extra alter command is not there in this case.

I am new to Hibernate, so I am finding it difficulty in understanding the explanation given in Hibernate docs, what is the purpose of `@MapsId`, when we have to use it and how it affects the underlying database schema.

Also I have gone through this SO post - [can someone please explain me @MapsId in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923643/can-someone-please-explain-me-mapsid-in-hibernate) but I am not able to get clear information on this annotation.

Comment: I use mapping only with a `Map`. So my mapping id is the key of it. Some times, it is more convenient than a `List` or a `Set`

Answer (score 0):

@MapsId is used to tell hibernate (or any JPA provider, actually) to use the same id of another entity with a 1-to-1 relationship with this one.

This will avoid to use an extra column to store the reference between the two entitities, while at the same being able to have a bidirectional relationship.